# Smarty include getting illegal string on string error

Tags: smarty

How to fix Smarty in civicrm 5.63.1

The error originates in the following include from sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%1D/1DB/1DB03A28%%CustomField.tpl.php

Message TypeError: Cannot access offset of type string on string in include() (line 31 of .../sites/default/files/civicrm/templates_c/en_US/%%1D/1DB/1DB03A28%%CustomField.tpl.php)

Then:
#0... vendor/civicrm/civicrm-packages/Smarty/Smarty.class.php:include() line 1914.

Comment: Can you include steps to reproduce this?

Comment: Yes please give context - what menu item are you clicking on that gives this error?

Answer (score 1):

This was fixed but missed making into 5.63.1. See https://github.com/civicrm/civicrm-core/pull/26517#issuecomment-1636255789

You can apply the patch there.

Comment: Aha! I was thinking that we fixed those in 5.63.1.